# Retrofit - Append dynamic queries after hard coded queries inserted

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to set queries after hard coded queries inserted.

my API address is :

```
    myapiaddress/names?q=Yoni&gender=Man&(here i need to enter dynamic queries)
```

my API call :

```
@GET("names")
Call<List<Integer>> searchNames(
    @Query("q") String q,
    @Query("gender") Gender gender);
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the code like following to make it generic and you can pass as many parameters as you want.

```
 public interface LoadDataService {
            @GET
            Call<List<Integer>> searchNames(@Url String url, @QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
        }

    APIs.LoadDataService service = retrofit.create(APIs.LoadDataService.class);
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("name","q");
            parameters.put("gender","Male");
    Call<List<Integer>> call = service.searchNames(APIs.GET_NAMES, parameters);
```

Comment: is there any answer without retrofit lib, kindly guide me about this issue i cant find this solution .@Usman Rana

Comment: By without retrofit you mean simple HTTP request?

Comment: by using volley or gson lib

Comment: You can write a method to which you pass url and hashMap. And apply itteration on hashMap to get key and value next the the url.